# how to pass script tag contain javascript library into a php file

Tags: javascript, php, moodle

for your more information i'm working on moodle LMS and there is a php file in a module that has a return array.
that return array consists of some fields like template,javascript and etc.
till now i could run some javascript codes in that javascript field, same as below:

```
  return array(
            'templates' => '',
            'javascript' => 'alert("text")',
            'otherdata' => ''
        );
```

now my question is that how can i pass a script tag of javascript library?
this library would be processed in the other side.
thanks

Comment: Do you want to pass something like `<script src="script.js"></script>`?

Comment: yes @ChrisSatchell

Comment: This is very specific question related to moodle templating, it would help moodle experts to find your question if you tag it so

Comment: did you find a solution to this?